# List widget listing only last hash value ruby - warning: duplicated key at line xx ignored: :label

Tags: ruby

## dashing start

> sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47: warning: duplicated key at
>   line 47 ignored: :label sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47:
>   warning: duplicated key at line 47 ignored: :value
>   sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47: warning: duplicated key at
>   line 47 ignored: :label sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47:
>   warning: duplicated key at line 47 ignored: :value
>   sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47: warning: duplicated key at
>   line 47 ignored: :label sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb:47:
>   warning: duplicated key at line 47 ignored: :value

```
{"a"=>1}  
1
{"b"=>2}
2
{"c"=>1}
1
{"d"=>2}
2

{:label=>"d", :value=>"2"}
```

> It just prints the last hash label(d) and value . Same appears in
>   list widget in dashboard. Could you please let me know how I could
>   bring other label and values values?

### List.rb

```
    require "mysql2"

    SCHEDULER.every '5s' do

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "10.2.2.1",:username => "abcuser",:database => 'testdb')

po1 = nil  

po2 = nil

po3 = nil

po4 = nil

p1=client.query("SELECT count(*) as p1 FROM testdb.tab1 WHERE (p='1')")

p2=client.query("SELECT count(*) as p2 FROM testdb.tab1 WHERE (p='2')")

p3=client.query("SELECT count(*) as p3 FROM testdb.tab1 WHERE (p='3')")

p4=client.query("SELECT count(*) as p4 FROM testdb.tab1 WHERE (p='4')")

p1.each do |i|
    puts i  # Prints {"a"=>1}
    puts i['p1'] #Prints 1
    po1 = i['p1']
    end

p2.each do |i|
        puts i # Prints {"b"=>2}
        puts i['p2'] # Prints 2
        po2 = i['p2'] 
        end

p3.each do |i|
        puts i # Prints {"c"=>1}
        puts i['p3'] # Prints 1
        po3 = i['p3'] 
        end

p4.each do |i|
        #puts i # Prints {"d"=>1}
        #puts i['p4'] # Prints 2
        po4 = i['p4'] 
        end

po = [ { :label=> "a", :value=> "#{po1}", :label=> "b", :value=> "#{po2}", :label=> "c", :value=> "#{po3}", :label=> "d", :value=> "#{po4}" } ]

    send_event('priority', { items: po })   
    end
```

Comment: Please show your code - especially `sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.rb` around line 17. And tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @spickermann : Thanks Spickermann for helping.Please find the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct hash because you're repeating the keys `:label` and `:value`

```
po = [ { :label=> "a", :value=> "#{po1}", :label=> "b", :value=> "#{po2}", :label=> "c", :value=> "#{po3}", :label=> "d", :value=> "#{po4}" } ]
```

You need to reorganize it into an array of small hashes, not an array of one big hash.

```
po = [ { :label=> "a", :value=> "#{po1}"}, {:label=> "b", :value=> "#{po2}"}, {:label=> "c", :value=> "#{po3}"}, {:label=> "d", :value=> "#{po4}" } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting . please see my comments I have added to Gerry. I am looking for how to maintain the key names (label and value) with different values stored on them.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: If you want to keep key names with different values, you could use arrays, e.g. `label: ['a', 'b', 'c'], value: ["#{po1}", "#{po2}", "#{po3}"]` but that puts an order dependency (the second entry n `:label` corresponds with the seocnd entry in `:value`) and also makes it hard to read the sets.  I would suggest my posted answer is the better way to go.

Comment: But basically, in a Ruby hash, you CANNOT have two different `:label =>` entries... there's no way to know which one to retrieve when you do `my_hash[:label]` so the last one encountered always replaces the previous one.